# Upload a file of a certain name length

Tags: php, file, upload

My code looks like this:

```
$uploaded=0;
$ext="";

$uploaded_file_name= strtolower($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

$name_file = explode('.', strtolower(basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])));
$file_name= $name_file[0];
$file_ext=$name_file[1];
$file_length=strlen($file_name);

$i=strlen($file_name);
while ($i++<8) {
    $file_name .= "0";
}
echo "file_name.ext =" . $file_name . "." . $file_ext;

//do we have a file?
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0))
{


   if ((($file_ext == "jpg")||($file_ext == "png")) && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 100000)&&(($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")||($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/png")))
   {
   //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
    $newname = "images/backgrounds/" . $file_name . "." . $file_ext;

       if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname)))
       {
       echo "File uploaded successfully!";
       $uploaded=1;
       }
       else
       {
        echo "Error:!";
        print('<p><a href="../../admin.php?">Back</a></p>');
       }
   } else {
   echo "Error: Only .jpg or .png files are allowed less than 100Kb";
   print('<p><a href="../../admin.php">Back</a></p>');
   }
} else {
echo "Error! File is not uploaded!";
print('<p><a href="../../admin.php">Back</a></p>');
}
```

The file name is corrected and filled up with `0` if it is too short. I tried to upload a file with extensions .jpg .jpeg .pnp

Apache shows me the errors:

```
[Mon Feb 24 16:51:54.754787 2014] [:error] [pid 2620] [client 127.0.0.1:39685] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(images/backgrounds/on-off00.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/BB/core/functions/admin_background.php on line 49, referer: http://localhost/BB/admin.php
[Mon Feb 24 16:51:54.754813 2014] [:error] [pid 2620] [client 127.0.0.1:39685] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpmbc7kZ' to 'images/backgrounds/on-off00.jpg' in /var/www/BB/core/functions/admin_background.php on line 49, referer: http://localhost/BB/admin.php
[Mon Feb 24 16:51:54.754844 2014] [:error] [pid 2620] [client 127.0.0.1:39685] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/BB/core/functions/admin_background.php on line 69, referer: http://localhost/BB/admin.php
```

What could be the reason that it cannot find the file in the /tmp directory?

Comment: Try use an absolute path for $newname, which will begin with "/", or something like dirname( __FILE__ ).'/images....'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newname = "images/backgrounds/" . $file_name . "." . $file_ext;
This should contain the full path where you are going to save the image.These messages are   related to incorrect path in server. 
Try to check if "images" Or "background" folder exists before uploading. 
 If these exist then check the full path with is_dir() function
```